# Function name as Object value

Tags: javascript

I need to selectively run several functions depending on various situations. I have a basic object like this:

```
object = {
  whatever : {
    objects : null
  },
  something : {
    objects : // some object
  }
};
```

I need to iterate through the object values and if `objects` is `not null`, I need to run a specific function. If `whatever.objects` is not null, I need to run `whateverFunction();`. If `something.objects` is not null, I need to run `somethingFunction();`.

```
for( i in object )
{
  if ( object[i].objects )
    // run a certain function
}
```

What is the best way to run these artibtrarily named functions based off of the values in the object? I could store the name of the "function-to-be-run" in the object and `eval()` it, but I'd like to try to avoid evaling.

Would it make more sense to create an class object each with it's own function to be run, and if so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
object = {
  whatever : {
    objects : null,
    func : whateverFunction
  },
  something : {
    objects : // some object,
    func : somethingFunction
  }
};

for (var i in object) {
  if (object[i].objects) {
    objects[i].func();
  }
}
```

Functions are themselves objects which can be passed around and stored. No need to store the function's name; store the function itself.

Comment: For reference: functions are themselves objects, so can be passed around and stored. So, no need to store the function's name; store the function itself. (If the situation allows, that is.)

Comment: @Matchu Haha, I was working on that explanation but you beat me to it.

Comment: does the function have to be defined here in the object? Or can it be defined elsewhere? I have some rather large complicated functions that would make the object pretty messy.

Comment: @Jakobud "func : somethingfunc" is just a property assignment. The keyword somethingfunc can be a function you defined elsewhere in your program. Note that this is very easy to test for yourself, just start up rhino.

Answer (score 1):

If `whateverFunction()` and `somethingFunction()` are global, try something like this

```
var funcName = 'somethingFunction';

window[funcName]();
```